# How do I fit an image inside of this specified grid space?

Tags: css, image, image-scaling

I'm trying to fit an image inside of the grid area that I've specified but everything I've tried isn't giving me the result I want.

I want the image to fill the space without cropping the image. Is that possible?

Result of Code below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTxh1.jpg

Original Image I would like to fit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoLYl.jpg

```
body{
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
     color: black;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
     }
.container{
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns:repeat(5, 1fr);
     grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 3fr 1fr;
     height: 100vh;
     }
.image{
     background-image: url(./assets/header_img.jpg);
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     grid-area: 1/1/3/-1;
     object-fit: fill;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Link your CSS stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">nav</div>
    <div class="image">image</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Of course! Just posted it

Comment: Great, I just added an answer, please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `background-size: 100% 100%;` and it will fill it comletely without cropping it.  Though it will stretch the image to fit the grid.

See here:

```css
body{
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
     color: black;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
     }
.container{
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns:repeat(5, 1fr);
     grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 3fr 1fr;
     height: 100vh;
     }
.image{
     background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/c3jpM7D.jpeg);
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     grid-area: 1/1/3/-1;
     object-fit: fill;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Link your CSS stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">nav</div>
    <div class="image">image</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
```